# What does the message "WEBGL_debug_renderer_info is deprecated in Firefox and will be removed. Please use RENDERER." mean?

Tags: firefox, webgl

On Firefox 92, if you do something like

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

var debugInfo = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');
var vendor = gl.getParameter(debugInfo.UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL);
var renderer = gl.getParameter(debugInfo.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL);

console.log(vendor);
console.log(renderer);
```

It will show a message saying
`WEBGL_debug_renderer_info is deprecated in Firefox and will be removed. Please use RENDERER.`

What does it mean?

The [relevant MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_debug_renderer_info) didn't even mention anything about it being deprecated like it normally does.

And there's no WebGL extentions or methods in the WebGL API called RENDERER.
Google isn't any help either.

Comment: I wonder if this is why Figma.com doesn't render in Firefox

Answer (score 10):

Apparently, you're meant to do this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

gl.getParameter(gl.RENDERER)
```

Anyway, feel free to delete this question.

But I'm leaving it because there's no results when you google that warning message and hope this question can change that.

Comment: I don't see why you would delete this question. If it helps, then it's useful! It's the top result when you google t he message!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where I was not calling

```
gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');
```

first. I had just been calling

```
const vendor = gl.getParameter(37455);  // Underlying value of debugInfo.UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL
const renderer = gl.getParameter(37456); // Underlying value of debugInfo.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL
```

And this gave me the error:
`getParameter: invalid parameter name WEBGL_debug_renderer_info not enabled`.

I had tried using the suggested `gl.RENDERER`, but that was not specific enough for what I wanted to do. The answer did help point me in the right direction of enabling the extension first (with getExtension), even when I know what the magic numbers will be.

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs, it appears that it's only deprecated in Firefox. Digging a little deeper I think it has to do with privacy and the ability to how the API exposes information that can be used for fingerprinting

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1722782